# Any text editor recommendations for java?

Tags: java, text-editor

I am new to coding and am currently learning java. I wanted to know which text editor would be best for me to start with.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Please read http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information then fix your question and we will reopen it, thanks!

Comment: Is there any reason to use Java, which seems to have fallen out of fashion, as opposed to, say, Python?

Answer (score 1):

There are many text editors out there, but the ones I hear the most about are : Netbeans, Eclipse and IntelliJ

I personally use Netbeans but that is because that's what we use for our java class.

Comment: Those are not actually text editors - they are IDEs. But that's just fine (+1), because, even though he doesn't know it, the OP needs an IDE. The debugger is your best friend - learn to use it.